# Handle large data and drawings - React Redux Immutable

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm developing a software which is drawing some elements on the screen which is using by mechanical engineers.

I'm string my project data in reducer store. This project data has tons of objects, arrays etc. I mean for each element on the screen, there is a data stored in project.

When user makes an action, I must recalculate project and set it to redux store again for example;

```
...
      case SET_ACTIVE_UNIT:
        let unit = action.unit;
        project = state.get('project').toJS(); //I'm using immutable
        project = ProjectLogic.addActiveUnit(project, unit, action.shiftKey);
        return state.set('project', fromJS(project));

...
```

Ok, you will say that this kind of usage is not right. Because I'm reading all data and reseting it to reducer whole data. You will advice me to use `state.setIn` but it is really imposible. Beacuse in addActiveUnit function will recalculate project, %20 of project data will be changed. So, I can't handle this change `state.setIn`

My problem starts here; if there is 60-80 elements drawing on the screen after `return state.set('project', fromJS(project));` rendering performance slows down. Every new items gets it worse.

How can I handle this problem?

Thanks all

Comment: Do ALL of the draw change based on the new item inserted?

Comment: Not always, but I can say yes.

Answer (score 1):

As a general observation, [`toJS()` is considered to be the most expensive API in Immutable.js](https://twitter.com/leeb/status/746733697093668864?lang=en), and should be avoided as much as possible.

My initial advice would be [to *not* use Immutable.js](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4rcqpx/dan_abramov_redux_is_not_an_architecture_or/d51g4k4?context=3).

Instead, you might want to look at using [`immer`](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) to handle the immutable update logic.

Also, our new [`redux-starter-kit` package](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org) uses Immer internally.

Beyond that, I'd suggest doing some profiling to see where exactly the perf bottlenecks actually are.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I will try it. But my problem is not about toJS() because It makes me on return state.set('project', fromJS(project)); line.